# Get particular value from php variables in text box using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

PHP CODE(plan-api.php)

```
$requestUrl = "url.com";
$response = (file_get_contents($requestUrl, false, $context));
$data = (json_decode($response, true));

echo $data["data"][0][recharge_amount];
echo "<br>";
echo $data["data"][0][recharge_talktime];
echo "<br>";
echo $data["data"][1][recharge_amount];
echo "<br>";
echo $data["data"][1][recharge_talktime];
echo "<br>";
echo $data["data"][2][recharge_amount];
echo "<br>";
echo $data["data"][2][recharge_talktime];
echo "<br>";
```

HTML/AJAX CODE(plan-ajax.php)

```
Please enter a Mobile number
<input type="text" id="search">
<br>
<input type="text" id="result">
<input type="text" id="result1">
<input type="text" id="result2">
<input type="text" id="result3">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').keypress(function(){
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "plan-api.php",
            data: 'result=' + $('#search').val(),

            success: function(output){
            $('#result').val(output);

        }


    }); // Ajax Call



}); //event handler


}); //document.ready
</script>
```

OUTPUT(**all in textbox having id "result"**)

10
7.77
20
15.54
30
23.32

but i want to get output :
`echo $data["data"][0][recharge_amount]` in textbox id "result"
`echo $data["data"][1][recharge_amount]` in textbox id "result1"
`echo $data["data"][2][recharge_amount]` in textbox id "result2"

and so on....

Comment: Do you try to return JSON and HTML from server at the same time?

Comment: send the data back as json so you can iterate response and assign to proper element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have not mistyped anything.

PHP:

```
<?php

/*
 * We assume your data has this structure, for example:
 * 
$data['data'][0]['recharge_amount'] = 10;
$data['data'][0]['recharge_talktime'] = 5;
$data['data'][1]['recharge_amount'] = 11;
and so on
*/

// we output the data as JSON
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

HTML / JS

```
Please enter a Mobile number
<input type="text" id="search">
<br>
<input type="text" id="result0">
<input type="text" id="result1">
<input type="text" id="result2">
<input type="text" id="result3">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').keypress(function(){
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "plan-api.php",
            data: 'result=' + $('#search').val(),
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(responseText){
                $.each(responseText.data, function(key,value){
                    $('#result'+key).val(value.recharge_amount);
                });
            }

        }); // Ajax Call
    }); //event handler

}); //document.ready
</script>
```

btw. I have changed id="result" to id="result0" for ease.

EDIT: actually a part of my php was redundant, so I changed it.

Comment: Sorry, one superfluous bracket. I just removed it and tested the updated code and it works.
Have you also linked to JQuery?